# Create a Class on XNA WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, xna

i had success to create xna winform just like 
    [WinForms Series 1: Graphics Device](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)
 tutorial. well, now i like to create some class to draw a component based by class

in xna there are several "protected void" to build a game on : **DrawableGameComponent**, but this is an xna winform so we have to create own graphicdevice.
in xna, take a look at this "protected void" code below:

```
      public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)

        {                                            

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

i want these codes above work in class with own graphicdevice
so, How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your game component which is inhereted from `DrawableGameComponent` to the `Game.Components` collection.

Also, you don't need to make your own graphics device.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a WinForms application, you won't rely on the `Draw` and `Update` methods to tell you when to draw and update; instead you can override the Windows `OnPaintBackground` method. For updating, you can use a `Timer` object.

Comment: i wrote it all on class file, how can i accesss the timer in class?

Comment: The `Timer` would be on the `Form`, and every time it fires you would call whatever `Update` methods or logic that you needed.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to be writing this project in WinForms? XNA will run in Windows without WinForms. Normally you would use WinForms to write your game editor, or to give some XNA graphical capability to a WinForms application. If this project is a game, you probably wouldn't want to use WinForms.

Comment: yes, i need the xna graphic running over winform. also,  many advantages that couldn't be found on winform. for example: they support PNG format it cause i'm thingking to use xna graphic on winform.